# How to ignore a file in Meteor.js?

Tags: file, meteor

Needs to include this file (http://trailers.apple.com/appletv/us/js/application.js) in a Meteor.js project.

The file can't be in the public folder, and it has to be under PROJECT_ROOT/appletv/us/js/ folder.

But whenever I include the file, it crashes Meteor.

Any advice on how to ignore this arbitrary file in an arbitrary folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't it be in `/public`? `/public` is copied to the root of the server when deployed. So `/public/appletv/us/js/application.js` will be `app.com/appletv/us/js/application.js` when running.

Comment: If in /public, it will not be bundled with others js files, in other words, another round trip to get this particular file.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
atv = {};
```

To the first line of this application.js

**Other solution**

Move your application.js to /lib, then create /lib/lib/hack.js
So your project will be:

```
<project>/lib/lib/hack.js
<project>/lib/application.js
<project>/*stuff*
```

And put

```
atv = {};
```

As the content of hack.js

Comment: For sure. In my "other solution" i use the fact that /lib folders is always loaded before the files in that folder. So, all files in /lib/lib is loaded before /lib, and all files in /lib are loaded before / http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: but where did this `atv` var come from?

Comment: Take a look at http://trailers.apple.com/appletv/us/js/application.js posted by the author of this question. This file is making atv.config = { ... }, but atv was not previously initialized as object. All i do is to initialize atv with atv = {}, to make application.js work.