# Use Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 with Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use the latest Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 with Meteor. I tried to install it using bower, but Meteor threw an error because of some HTML or JS included in the bootstrap package (the `_includes` directory). I am aware that meteor has a [bootstrap package](http://docs.meteor.com/#bootstrap), however this is Bootstrap 2.3.

I wonder if there's a way to either ignore certain files so that Meteor will not try and serve these files, or other way to get around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now here's my solution, as inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16202716/1368032):

I install Bootstrap with bower with the following `.bowerrc` config:

```
{
     "directory": "public/bower_components"
}
```

From here, you can use Bootstrap by either include it directly in your `<head>` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Or you can use it in your less files like this

```
@import "public/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

Thanks to @majodev for his help. I think `bootstrap3-less` is nice, but by using it we're introducing another dependency of that package's developer updating to the latest Bootstrap releases. By [using bower](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), we know we will always have the latest version of bootstrap available, or whatever version of it we want.

**Update 8/9/13:**

To use `bootstrap.js`, the current workaround is to create a package that calls the bootstrap.js file. Here's how I do it:

Create a `bootstrap` directory in `packages`

```
packages
└── bootstrap
    └── package.js
```

Then in `package.js`, declare the `js` files you'd like to include, for example:

```
// package.js

Package.describe({
    summary: "Load bootstrap script."
});

Package.on_use(function(api) {
    api.add_files(['../../public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'], 'client');
});
```

Comment: Looks like there's an official bootstrap package, but I'm not sure how to link it in my HTML file. Or is it already linked when I add the package.

Comment: Yes I believe you can do `meteor add bootstrap` and it is automatically linked, and you can start using it.

Comment: Is there a way to disable bootstrap for certain templates?

Comment: Why add another package manager to the existing one? Especially one that adds it's name to the production folder.

Comment: @curieux this answer is more than a year old. I haven't played with Meteor much lately, but I'm sure there's a newer and better way to do this.

Comment: @TriNguyen Yes, there are several ways. A notable list of bootstrap related libraries is here : https://atmospherejs.com/packages/bootstrap3 while a fresh, configurable and meteorish one is here : https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap, my thought is that Meteor has its own package manager fully capable of maintaining its internals and the libraries, adding another one will only complicate things on long term. Sorry for nagging.

Comment: @curieux as I said, this was a very OLD solution. this probably does not apply anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the custom atmosphere package [bootstrap3-less](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/bootstrap3-less)?

ad. question: I know that the test subdirectory will be ignored on clients/server, but that's just an awful place. Have you tried putting it into lib/external? The [Unofficial Meteor FAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files) might also be a good starting point.

Comment: Will meteor ignore `/lib/external` as well?

Comment: As mentioned @ the unofficial FAQ: "common code from someone else. Note that js files in lib folders are loaded before other js files." Are you really sure, that you want to ignore those files? Normally I would serve other libs in client/lib, if there's no atmosphere package available (but there is!).

Comment: well if it isn't ignored the stuff in the `_includes` folder from boostrap will yield a bunch of errors, as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Have you tried following the solution from an other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160295/how-to-ignore-a-file-in-meteor-js

Answer (score 0):

One should NOT use any more a specific method or package to add Bootstrap features to Meteor as Bootstrap is now officially released as a Meteor package.

See 3.3.4 changelog http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/03/16/bootstrap-3-3-4-released/

> [Bootstrap is now also available as a Meteor package in the Atmosphere package index.](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap)