# Missing something trying to get bootstrap included into meteor as a local git submodule

Tags: javascript, css, git, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to install a local copy of bootstrap into a meteor project to make it easier to customise it.

I was using the bootsrap-3 smart package and it was working pretty well, so removed that, created the directory tree and files described in [Use Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110976/use-twitter-bootstrap-3-rc1-with-meteor) and executed meteor add bootstrap which displayed the text from the summary string, but, no bootstrap is included in the project.

I added bootstrap with

```
git submodule add git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git public/bootstrap
```

and adjusted the paths appropriately in the packages/bootstrap/package.js file (even tried absolute paths to try and get it to work).

package.js looks like

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Load locale bootstrap scripts"
});

Package.on_use(function(api) {
  api.add_files('../../public/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'client');
});
```

I'm missing something, but struggling to find it.

Peter

Comment: Did you add it back to .meteor/packages file so it knows to load that package?

Comment: Yes, it is in the .meteor packages file (just the one line, bootstrap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stick to the standard way of creating packages by just putting Bootstrap 3's `css`, `fonts`, and `js` directories at the top-level of your package directory, and link to them like this in `package.js`:

```
api.add_files('css/bootstrap.css', 'client');
api.add_files('js/bootstrap.min.js', 'client');
...
```

If you care about the icons, add the fonts the same way.  Then, create an override css file which loads last, overriding the paths to the icons in the Bootstrap css.  An example of this override file is in Meteor's official Bootstrap 2 package, [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-override.css). Also see the `package.js` file from the same, [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/bootstrap/package.js) (though I think you could skip using NPM to concatenate the path names).

Comment: I must be really missing something here. I decided that I needed to use the glyphicons in the app, so decided to migrate to this approach.

I added the css, js and fonts directories from bootstrap3 to the packages directory and put bootstrap-overide.css there as well, made a bootstrap3 directory and added a packages.js file to it with the above code, but when I try and do meteor add bootstrap3 I get errors about files not found. I move the css, js, font dirs and overide file down into the bootstrap3 directory with the packages.js and the same problem. Where should they be?

Comment: Sorted... changed my package to bootstrap3-local and it seems to have sorted out the confusion (in my mind as well..) Yay.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to add bootstrap is just to place the files in your client directory, probably at `client/lib`.  That is the simplest way if you are going to maintain and customise the files yourself.  You will probably want both the .css and .js from bootstrap.

For a package, I would look at [bootstrap3-less](https://github.com/eprochasson/bootstrap3-less).  It can be added with meteorite and gives you the less files which you can customise.  If that doesn't suit you then you can at least see how the package.js there looks and how the package is organised.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll give the client/lib bit a try rather than the packages. The problem with the meteroite packages (and its probably not really a problem) is that they are simlinks outside the application tree which means any overide files in the package directory can't be added to git as far as I can see.